# Django 'str' object has no attribute 'values' in rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I use rest_framework to implement the api

models.py:

```
class Store(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
```

myapp/api.py:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Store

class StoreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Store.objects.all()

    serializer_class = StoreSerializer

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

project/api.py

```
v1 = routers.DefaultRouter()
v1.register('store',StoreViewSet)
v1.register('stores/menu_item',MenuItemViewSet)
```

urls.py

```
    from .api import v1

    urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^api/v1/', include(v1.urls)),

    ]
```

I met the following traceback

> AssertionError at /api/v1/store/
>   ("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '**all**' to the StoreSerializer serializer.",)

So I add the `fields = '__all__'` to fix this error

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   fields = '__all__'

   class Meta:
       model = Store
```

But next I met this [traceback](http://dpaste.com/0E54BZJ)

Based on that traceback I don't know which part is missing.

Comment: whats v1.urls ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Put it inside Meta:

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
```

[specifying-fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include)

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include

Comment: Such a small mistake and took me 24 hours to realize, I love you for this answer @Bear Brown

Answer (score 0):

Set fields in the Meta subclass to`'__all__'`